# Python Error With Pickle

Tags: python

I have been writing a text based File System. To save the data I had to write it to a file, so I used Pickle. It seemed to be working fine before I added the second Pickle. Anyhow it is giving me this error:

[image]

Then here is my code:

```
import datetime
import time
import pickle

file_Name = "testfile"
file_Name2 = "testfile2"

accounts = {}
files = {}

fileObject2 = open(file_Name2,'r')  
accounts = pickle.load(fileObject2)

fileObject = open(file_Name,'r')  
files = pickle.load(fileObject)

def startup():
    fileObject2 = open(file_Name2,'wb')
    pickle.dump(accounts, fileObject2)   
    fileObject2.close()
    print "\n          -------------------          "
    print "          FILE SYSTEM MANAGER          "
    print "          -------------------          "
    print "\n To login type in: LOGIN"
    print " To create a new account type in: ACCOUNT"
    loginornew = raw_input("\n Please enter LOGIN or ACCOUNT: ")
    if loginornew.lower() == "login":
        login()
    elif loginornew.lower() == "account":
        newaccount()
    else:
        startup()

def newaccout():
    print "--------------------------------------------"
    print "\n Would you like to create a new account?"
    yesorno = raw_input(" Please enter YES or NO: ")
    if yesorno.lower() == "no":
        startup()
    elif yesorno.lower() == "yes":
        newusername = raw_input("\n Please enter a username for your account: ")
        newpassword = raw_input(" Please enter a password for your account: ")
        newpasswordagain = raw_input(" Please confirm the password for your account: ")
        if newpassword == newpasswordagain:
            for username in accounts:
                if username == newusername:
                    print "\n Username already exists"
                    print " Please try again"
                    newaccount()
                else:
                    pass
            accounts[newusername] = newpassword
            print "\n Account Created"
            startup()
        else:
            print "\n Passwords do not match"
            print " Please try again"
            newaccount()
    else:
        newaccount()

def login():
    print "--------------------------------------------"
    print "\n Would you like to login?"
    yesorno = raw_input(" Please enter YES or NO: ")
    if yesorno.lower() == "no":
        startup()
    elif yesorno.lower() == "yes":
        username = raw_input("\n Please enter your username: ")
        password = raw_input("\n Please enter your password: ")
        for usernames in accounts:
            if username == usernames:
                for passwords in accounts.keys():
                    if password == passwords:
                        print "\n Access Granted"
                        print "\n--------------------------------------------"
                        menu()
                    else:
                        login()
                print "\n Access Denied"
                print "\n Please try again"
                print "\n--------------------------------------------"
                login()
            elif usernames != usernames:
                print "\n Access Denied"
                print "\n Please try again"
                print "\n--------------------------------------------"
                login()
            else:
                login()
    else:
        login()

def menu():
    fileObject = open(file_Name,'wb')
    pickle.dump(files, fileObject)   
    fileObject.close()
    print "\n          -------------------          "
    print "          FILE SYSTEM MANAGER          "
    print "          -------------------          "
    print "\n What would you like to do with your files?"
    print "   To make a new file type in: NEW"
    print "   To edit a current file type in: EDIT"
    print "   To delete a current file type in: DELETE"
    print "   To view all current files type in: ALL"
    chooser = raw_input("\n Please enter NEW, EDIT, DELETE, or ALL: ")
    if chooser.lower() == "new":
        newfile()
    elif chooser.lower() == "edit":
        editfiles()
    elif chooser.lower() == "delete":
        deletefiles()
    elif chooser.lower() == "all":
        allfiles()
    else:
        menu()

def newfile():
    filename = ""
    filetext = ""
    while filename == "":
        print "--------------------------------------------"
        filename = raw_input("\n Please input your new files name: ")
    while filetext == "":
        filetext = raw_input("\n Please input the text for your new file: ")
    filedate = datetime.date.today()
    files[filename] = {filedate:filetext}
    print "\n File Added"
    print "\n--------------------------------------------"
    menu()

def editfiles():
    print "--------------------------------------------"
    print " To edit a file type in: EDIT"
    print " To view all current files type in: ALLFILES"
    print " To cancel type in: CANCEL"
    wheretogo = raw_input("\n Please enter EDIT, ALLFILES, or CANCEL: ")
    if wheretogo.lower() == "edit":
        print "\n To edit a file type in its name"
        print " To cancel type in: CANCEL"
        print "\n **Please Note** Editing a file changes its date!"
        editname = raw_input("\n Please type in the file's name or CANCEL: ")
        if editname.lower() == "cancel":
            menu()
        else:
            newcontents = ""
            for filename in files:
                if filename.lower() == editname.lower():
                    print "\n What would you like this file to say?"
                    while newcontents == "":
                        newcontents = raw_input("\n Please input files new contents: ")
                    filetext = newcontents
                    filedate = datetime.date.today()
                    files[filename] = {filedate:filetext}
                    print "\n File Changed"
                    print "--------------------------------------------"
                    menu()
                else:
                    pass
            print "\n File not found!"
            editfiles()
    elif wheretogo.lower() == "allfiles":
        print "\n--------------------------------------------"
        for filename in files:
            print "File Name: " + str(filename)
        print "--------------------------------------------"
        print "\n To edit a file type in: EDIT"
        print " To cancel type in: CANCEL"
        print "\n **Please Note** Editing a file changes its date!"
        wheretogo = raw_input("\n Please enter EDIT or CANCEL: ")
        if wheretogo.lower() == "edit":
            editname = raw_input("\n Please type in the file's name to edit it: ")
            newcontents = ""
            for filename in files:
                if filename.lower() == editname.lower():
                    print "\n What would you like this file to say?"
                    while newcontents == "":
                        newcontents = raw_input("\n Please input files new contents: ")
                    filetext = newcontents
                    filedate = datetime.date.today()
                    files[filename] = {filedate:filetext}
                    print "\n File Changed"
                    print "--------------------------------------------"
                    menu()
                else:
                    pass
            print "\nFile not found!"
            editfiles()
        elif wheretogo.lower() == "cancel":
            menu()
        else:
            menu()
    elif wheretogo.lower() == "cancel":
        menu()
    else:
        menu()

def deletefiles():
    print "--------------------------------------------"
    print " To delete a file type in: DELETE"
    print " To view all current files type in: ALLFILES"
    print " To cancel type in: CANCEL"
    wheretogo = raw_input("\n Please enter DELETE, ALLFILES, or CANCEL: ")
    if wheretogo.lower() == "delete":
        print "\n To delete a file type in its name"
        print " To cancel type in: CANCEL"
        deletename = raw_input("\n Please type in the file's name or CANCEL: ")
        if deletename.lower() == "cancel":
            menu()
        else:
            for filename in files:
                if filename.lower() == deletename.lower():
                    del files[filename]
                    print "\n File Removed"
                    print "--------------------------------------------"
                    menu()
                else:
                    pass
            print "\n File not found!"
            deletefiles()
    elif wheretogo.lower() == "allfiles":
        print "\n--------------------------------------------"
        for filename in files:
            print "File Name: " + str(filename)
        print "--------------------------------------------"
        print "\n To delete a file type in: DELETE"
        print " To cancel type in: CANCEL"
        wheretogo = raw_input("\n Please enter DELETE or CANCEL: ")
        if wheretogo.lower() == "delete":
            deletename = raw_input("\n Please type in the file's name to delete it: ")
            for filename in files:
                if filename.lower() == deletename.lower():
                    del files[filename]
                    print "\n File Removed"
                    print "--------------------------------------------"
                    menu()
                else:
                    pass
            print "\nFile not found!"
            deletefiles()
        elif wheretogo.lower() == "cancel":
            menu()
        else:
            menu()
    elif wheretogo.lower() == "cancel":
        menu()
    else:
        menu()

def allfiles():
    filetexttotal = ""
    for filename in files:
        print "\n--------------------------------------------"
        print "\nFile Name: " + str(filename)
        for filedate in files[filename]:
            print "File Date: " + str(filedate)
            for filetext in files[filename][filedate]:
                filetexttotal = filetexttotal + str(filetext)
            print "File Contents: " + str(filetexttotal)
            filetexttotal = ""
    print "\n--------------------------------------------"
    menu()

login()
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of the [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)? It would probably help you find the errors yourself in your own code, and if you still can't solve it then it helps us help you.

Comment: You're not closing the file handles after you `load`.  Bad stuff ensues.  This is one of many reasons you should always use context managers to open (and implicitly `close()`) files.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open file with 'rb' mode. Like this:

```
...
fileObject2 = open(file_Name2,'rb')
...
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: He's dumping with protocol 0, which is the ASCII based protocol, so opening in `r` will actually work. Opening in `rb` is in fact best practice since it covers all platforms and protocols, but it won't address the OP's bug.

Comment: Hello, I tried to open the file with 'rb' but it will still not work.

Comment: Yea, everytime I run my code it just brings up the same error. I am sorry I can not figure it out, or I can not be a better help. I just found out about Pickle...